# How to create a shortcut for document library creation?

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-online

We are using O365/Sharepoint Online 2013. We have document centers for users and we use document libraries as the main level categories and then we have some files and a few sub-folders under them.

My question if possible, how can I make a link/button on the document center page that would initiate a new document library creation when clicked and then the user would just have to fill in the name of the new document library, click ok and have the new document library showing in the contents?

I know it's not a big deal to click "Site Contents" and then "Add an app" and then select the document library from there but it would be better if there were a link/button for that on the main page. ;)

Thanks!

Comment: This could be a silly question, but once you are inside your Document Library, wouldn't one option be to add a *New Folder* (Files->New Folder) inside the library? This of course doesn't add the new folder to the *Site Contents* page, but if you are worried about it getting crowded by document libraries, this would be an option.

Comment: Actually the problem is that we have lots and lots of files so one document library isn't enough (view limit of 5000 items) so that's why we have a document center where we use libraries as the top level "folders" or categories instead of making all the sub-folders/sub-categories under one document library. :)

Comment: Ah, alright. Well a lame solution would be bookmarking the URL http://yoursite.com/_layouts/15/new.aspx?FeatureId=%7B00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101%7D&ListTemplate=101& (This is the one on SP Server 2013). This URL is the one you get once navigating to *Site Contents* -> *add an app* -> *Document Library* -> *Advanced Options*.

Comment: Hmm that seems to be close, is there any way to get the simple creation so the user would only need to input the name and create it? :)

Comment: Well those are just the advanced options, so adding a description for example is optional. If you create a document library after inserting a name for it, and leave the rest of the fields as they are, the result should be the same as creating a document library without the advanced options.

Comment: Yep I know but we have some users that are not too tech-savvy so I'm trying to minimize the confusion for them as I'm the one they are coming with their complaints heh ;)

Comment: Well because this is already a lame answer (according to me), I'd just say "enter a name, leave rest as it is" :D  Well I tried checking if I could dig an URL for the dialog window which pops up with minimal document library creation options, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Yeah I got the address for the dialog window but there comes a new problem, once the user enters the name for the library and accepts, the library is created but it stays on a black white page and doesn't redirect back to the document center page. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using moe's approach of getting the hyperlink and using that as a base for the "New Document Library" -button/link. I kept on digging and found out the link that can be used to create a new Document Library with only the basic fields Name & Description. Here it is:

https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/site/_layouts/15/new.aspx?ListTemplate=101&

Big thanks to Moe for his "lame" solution that works for us perfectly! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using a drop off library and then create a rule based on metadata to automatically deploy the document in the correct document library. You could use this same meta tag data to display the content of the library based on the audience setting of the library (For example all users in the IT-department see only the document library which is set for for the IT department as audience)